# Why does onscroll work without parenthesis in this function?

Tags: javascript, html, onscroll

I have made 3 functions on calling the windowScroll function. Why does it not work with the extra parenthesis, but works when inside its own function or without parenthesis?

```
var windowScroll = function() {
    var doesNotRun = function() {
        console.log('does not run');
    };
    var doesRun = function() {
        console.log('does run');
    };
    window.onscroll = doesNotRun();
    window.onscroll = doesRun;
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
        doesRun();
    });
};
windowScroll();
```

Here is a link on codepen: http://codepen.io/marcoangelo/pen/KWdWem

Any help to understand why Javascript does this would be great.

Comment: In the first case you actually calling the new function created by *bind*, which doesn't have a return statement so you're setting *window.onscroll* to undefined. In strict mode, *this* will be undefined too (not that it matters in this case since whatever is passed to the function is not used).

Comment: I don't see why the massive downvoting is neccessary, this is a legit question. A little odd, but legit. Not everyone is a programming guru

Comment: thanks for the replies. I realise its not a decoration Denys, I am trying to understand why the language behaves like this. To me, I would have thought the doesNotRun function should work even without .bind(this) but it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign a *function object* to the event handler properties.

`doesRun` and `doesNotRun` are expressions that resolve to function objects.

`doesRun()` and `doesNotRun()` are expressions that (immediately) call those functions and resolve to the return value you get when you call them.  In this case, since the functions do not have `return` statements, that is `undefined`.